# sapling: How to change the commit editor

Tags: version-control, sapling

Meta's new Sapling SCM looks interesting, but can you change the commit editor, to e.g. vscode?

I can't find anything editor related in `sl config`.

Comment: Can anyone with 1500+ reputation add a sapling-scm tag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admittedly, config options need to be documented on the Sapling website. Until then, looking at historical Mercurial documentation is a good proxy.

For example, in this case, the config you want to set is `ui.editor`, just like in Mercurial. Though note that in the specific case of VS Code, you likely want to include the `--wait` flag, so I would set it as follows:

```
sl config --user ui.editor "/usr/local/bin/code --wait"
```